# My HTML is not sending the POST method to the flask app function

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

1. ## **What's happening:**

> I have an HTML code that is sending a POST request to the flask code. It's for a Login page. (I'm using SQLite3 and Flask.)

2. ## **The HTML code:**

```html
   <div class="col">
            <div class="login-box">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('register_post') }}">
                <div class="user-box">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                </div>
                <div class="user-box">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="user-box">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="button-form">        
                    <a id="submit" href="{{url_for('register_post')}}">Submit</a>
                    <div id="register">
                        Already Have An Account ?
                        <a href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login Now !</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

3. ## **The Python code:**

```py
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_post():
    print("Got a data")
    username = request.form['username']
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (?,?,?)''', (email, username, password))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

### **There isn't a traceback which (maybe) means the function hasn't even been called.**

Comment: You don't want to use a `a` to link to the register page. You want a `button` element of type `submit`. And it doesn't need an `href`. The `action` of the `form` specifies where the form is submitted to. I've never actually done what you're doing here, but I'm assuming the `a`nchor is navigating and not triggering the submission.

Comment: agreed. the `submit` should be of `type='submit'` and an input tag

Comment: You have `id="submit"` rather than `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with Flask, but have with Django.

I see you got an `<a>` tag with `href="{{url_for('register_post')}}"`, why are you trying to redirect to 'https://example.com/register'? By redirecting you are making `GET` request whereas your `register_post` function only handles `POST` method.

You described `<form>` with `method="post"` and `action="{{url_for('register_post')}}"`, this means that the function will work whenever someone submits the form, but for now it's possible when you click the 'enter' key when focused on any input of the form. Another way to do it is to add `<button type="submit">yout text</button>` or `<input type="submit" value="your text" />` instead of `<a id="submit">` tag.

There is only two methods of `HTTP` Request in `HTML` those being `POST` and `GET`.

- `GET` request occurs when you are navigating via URL or submit a form with `method="GET"` which is default and you do not have to specify it.
- `POST` method occurs when someone SUBMITS a FORM with POST method described.

If you want to access any other HTTP Requests kind of PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, then you need JavaScript for it.